# Making a asynchronous call

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a list `rms.PositiveResponse`, and another list `rms.NegativeResponses`. The Lists contain a `RecruitID` and a `Timestamp`. I have over 10,000 records.

I am getting this data from a web service.

```
RMSDataService.RMS rms = new RMSDataService.RMS();
var negList = rms.NegativeResponse.Where(d => d.RLMSTimeStamp != null && d.RLMSTimeStamp > new DateTime(2012, 02, 22));
var posList = rms.PositiveResponse.Where(d => d.RLMSTimeStamp != null && d.RLMSTimeStamp > new DateTime(2012, 02, 22));
```

I want to make a Asynchronous call, because a recruit ID can change from negative to positive list. How can I achieve that? I dont want to wait for I/O in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CallBacks` and `WaitHandles` to call your services asynchronously. Maybe [this](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2005/08/01/async_webservices.html) article can help.